# Canvas toDataURL not working for GIF or JPEG

Tags: html5-canvas, todataurl

I am using HTML canvas to send a dataURL to the server which is then saved to an image file using Perl. I need a jpeg or gif filetype (the only types supported by Perl module PDF::Create). However, no matter what I specify in the toDataURL I still get a PNG dataURL and can't create a jpeg or gif from this.
I'm using IE 11 in windows. Any ideas?

```
var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/gif');

var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Both result in:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...etc
```

Comment: IIRC `"image/gif"` is only supported in Safari and thus will indeed fallback to `"image/png"` in other browsers. But `"image/jpeg"` should work everywhere. Could you post a complete (but still minimal) example or even can you confirm that running [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLL0u78k/) you get `data:image/png;base64` in the prompt message?

Comment: Ok that fiddle did work. I'll start again from scratch and see if I can figure out where I went wrong